# How to track application sign-ins in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I know that to track user sign-ins I need to go to Active Directory -> (under Activity) Sign-ins, and have the necessary "Azure Active Directory Premium 2" subscription.

I am trying to find the equivalent for sign-ins via an access key of a given application created via app registrations.

Where can I see this in the Azure Portal? Bonus question: where is it available in the SDK or API?

Answer (score 1):

From Azure portal,

Go to App registrations -> filter listed application by app Id (access key) or name.

Which lead you to application blade,

[image]

Click on Managed application in local directory, which show you sign-ins option for this application

[image]

If you want to access your active directory application by API, [Office Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_list) can help.

Comment: Thank you!
Now to understand why my sign ins are not appearing there...

Comment: Question: I can't see sign-ins with the secret key. Is it possible that this sign-ins log only tracks user sign ins, and not sign-ins with a secret key?

Comment: yes, right sign-ins log only user info not secret key - we can get these much info from log - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-activity-sign-ins

Comment: I don't understand - so is there a way to get the logs of secret key sign-ins??

Comment: What is the meaning of secret key sign-ins here? azure active directory application's secret keys or access token generate by application after successful sign-ins? in both case i don't think so azure give you that info.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-activity-sign-ins

Do you have a Premium subscription? If you do not, you will not be able to see these logs.